# R - one_of with vector

Tags: r

I have got this dataframe

```
source_df <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(seq(1: 3)),
    nr = c(seq(1: 3)),
    ar = c(seq(1: 3)),
    br = c(seq(1: 3)),
    zr = c(seq(1: 3)),
    cn = c("us", "uk", "ca")
  )
```

I created simple function for select desired columns

```
selector <-
  function(df, colname) {


    variable <- paste("selected", colname, sep = "_")

    result <-
      df %>% 
      select(
        id,
        one_of(colname)
      ) %>% 
    rename(!!variable := one_of(colname))


    return(result)

  }
```

I call it this way.

```
result <-
  selector(
    df = source_df,
    colname = "nr"
  )
```

It works well but only if I use one column name as colname input, how should I improve my function to be able to work with parameter colname = c("nr", "zr", "br")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select` accepts string names as input. So you can do  :

```
library(dplyr)

selector <- function(df, colname) {
  df %>%  select(id, colname) %>% rename_at(vars(-id), ~paste0('selected_', .))
}

selector(source_df, c("nr", "zr"))

#  id selected_nr selected_zr
#1  1           1           1
#2  2           2           2
#3  3           3           3
```